# Return the largest number of occurences/repetitions/duplicates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

If you have a row of values, and some of them are duplicates, how can you return the largest number of repetitions?

In other words, is there a way for cell B2 below to run just one swift command instead of having to run a secondary function?

```
A   B
1   =MODE.SNGL(A:A) => 3
2   =COUNTIF(A:A, B1) => 5
3
3
3
3
3
2
1
4
4
5
```

Comment: You don't need **2** cells.............just embed your mode equation within the countif equation.............

Comment: Doing it in 1 cell is just semantics. My question is whether there's just one formula that can do this.

Comment: No, you can use 2 functions embedded.

Answer (score 2):

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,MODE.SNGL(A:A))
```

This is what Gary meant by embedding the formula inside one another.  If this was an IF function it would be referred to a nesting.

Comment: I wrote it as 2 formulas just to demonstrate that it's 2 formulas. Is there no direct (i.e. unnested) formula that does this?